# Iframe is working in my local system but not in fileserver

Tags: javascript, html, http, iframe

This code works in my chrome but not in fileserver.

```
 <body>
 <div> 
 <iframe src="http://www.yunoworldtech.com/" height="710px" width="99%">
  </iframe>
  </div></body>
```

The above is the link which I included in the iframe(code). I got successful implementation in local machine but on the file server, i am not able to load it.

> [File server link](https://dinuduke.000webhostapp.com/my_app.html)
>   Help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('https://hootsuite.com') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin ('https://dinuduke.000webhostapp.com').

You got the CORS problem. You request a resource from other domain and the other domain by default not authorize such request. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: "You got the CORS" — It has nothing to do with CORS. CORS is a completely different spec to `postMessage`. That isn't even the most significant error message the page is reporting.

Comment: guys don't play here for few points. if u can't help don't over react and if u can help then do so...